# How to expand my camera view?

Tags: camera

I'm asking how to make my camera see a lot more without having to zoom out. Because if I zoom out everything is smaller, I want it just close enough but I want it to see everything. I don't want it to look further away, but I want it to see more. [image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, because the only two ways to get more view in camera is to move it, or zoom out.

Comment: @David The gray thing around the camera view represents the unseen ones, right? All I want to have is that I want to see everything that I can see from the perspective of the image above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make objects near the camera look bigger](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78638/how-to-make-objects-near-the-camera-look-bigger)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos nope. That is literally like zooming in and out. I want the camera to see more stuff without having to move and zoom the camera.

Comment: I may be wrong but you can change the [focal length of the camera](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Understanding_the_Camera).

Comment: Does it help if you select your camera in the Properties panel, then change the Focal Length to, say 8mm? If you are using an orthographic camera, try using a different scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping up comments section with additional gifs.

### Moving camera:

[image: camera_move]

You can move **Camera** in many ways.

1. Grab it with <kbd>G</kbd>.
2. Fly with it <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.
3. Or just **Lock Camera to View** and move around like in *Viewport*.

In example above I've locked camera and expanded its view along viewport.

### Change Focal Length:

[image]

Second option is **Focal Length** under **Camera** tab. This one seems to be solution for you as basically it will show you more without zooming in or out. Note that it will distort objects appearance. Lower values = more distortion.

After lowering value you will need to move camera towards objects.

Comment: Adding to cgslav 's comment. Try changing the focal type. ie. the Perspective, Orthographic or panoramic buttons above the focal l bit. I just tried his method and trying these extra options out got just what I needed. For me orthographic and changing the Focal length in that setting got a really good view without distorion.

Comment: The focal length value seems to be applicable to Perspective camera. With Orthogonal camera, change Orthographic scale for zooming in/out.