# I can't see half of the mesh in camera view

Tags: cycles-render-engine

After working a long time I made a preview in my camera view by pressing 0 .
I cant see half of the mesh I designed in my camera view

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: As a guess clipping values for camera are too low / too high. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance

Comment: Or maybe [how to expand my camera view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79116/how-to-expand-my-camera-view)

Answer (score 0):

Though you are not descriptive, I think I've had this problem before. Change the clipping values in your camera.

Comment: Hi. It would be useful if you could be descriptive of *where* these clipping values are, *what* values should be set and *why* this is effecting their scene.